# android html5 tabHost is accepted?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-widget

I am planning to build an aplication using html5 tabs instead a native tabHost controller but before keep going on, I am afraid if will be accepted or not by android market because I had problems using it in iOS. However this time is for android and google should be more permissive as apple. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no censorship in Android market at all! Everything you publish will be available for users (almost) instantly.

You will only have problems if you publish a malicious app or someone reports you for copyright infringements.